# How do I add a newline to a TextView in Android?

Tags: android, newline, textview

When I define a `TextView` in `xml`, how do I add a new line to it? `\n` seems not to work.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue"
   android:text="Line1 -\nLine2"
   android:layout_width="54dip"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textSize="11px" />
```

Comment: Your code does work for me. What do you get instead of multiline text?

Comment: In the visual editor it shows as textual \n

Answer (score 321, accepted):

Don't trust the Visual editor.
Your code does work in the emu.

Comment: well, in my case, the Visual editor was telling the truth. It was adding another backslash to display the backslash. The correct way was putting the text inside the xml file.

Comment: Visual editor said: "Why you don't trust me?" LOL

Answer (score 95):

Try:

`android:lines="2"`

`\n` should work.

Comment: my textview could be longer than 2 lines. Its a control. It can be just about anything.

Answer (score 46):

try `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

Answer (score 44):

I think this has something to do with your `HTM.fromHtml(subTitle)` call: a "\n" doesn't mean bupkis to HTML.  Try `<br/>` instead of "\n".

Comment: @androidevAlex That's because it's <br/>, not </br>

Answer (score 22):

First, put this in your textview:

```
android:maxLines="10"
```

Then use `\n` in the text of your textview.

maxLines makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. You may choose another number :)

Answer (score 22):

Tried all the above, did some research of my own resulting in the following solution for rendering line feed escape chars:

```
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

1. Using the replace method you need to filter **escaped** linefeeds (e.g. `'\\\n'`)
2. Only then each instance of line feed `'\n'` escape chars gets rendered into the actual linefeed

For this example I used a Google Apps Scripting noSQL database (ScriptDb) with JSON formated data.

Cheers :D

Comment: This worked for me: replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Comment: rather, string = string.replaceAll("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Answer (score 11):

Make sure your `\n` is in `"\n"` for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtTitlevalue"
   android:text="Line1: \r\n-Line2\r\n-Line3"
   android:layout_width="54dip"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:textSize="11px" />
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 9):

I just solve the same problem, put below attributes in xml

```
android:lines="2" android:maxLines="4" android:singleLine="false"
```

work.`Html.fromHtml("text1 <br> text2").toString()` also work.

Comment: This is still relevant, thanks! I had maxLines, but I didn't have singleLine=false.

Comment: This is the only solution which worked from me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My 2 cents, using Android TV.

Add `\n` in XML strings, while reading:

```
public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
    this.subtitle = subtitle.replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This solved my problem.

```
stringVar.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\\\n");
```

Answer (score 8):

One way of doing this is using `Html` tags::

```
txtTitlevalue.setText(Html.fromHtml("Line1"+"<br>"+"Line2" + " <br>"+"Line3"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Also you can add  `&lt;br&gt;` instead of `\n.`

And then you can add text to TexView:

```
articleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textForTextView));
```

Comment: Not in the XML you can't. It gives a compile error - `android:text` can't contain < or > characters.

Answer (score 6):

If you debug, you will see that the string is actually `"\ \r\ \n"` or `"\ \n"`, ie, it is escaped. So if you massage that string, to get rid of the extra `\`, you will have your solution. This is true especially if you are reading from a database.

Answer (score 6):

`System.getProperty("line.separator");` this work for me.

Comment: How did you use this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the `"\n"` in the `strings.xml` file not within the page layout.

Comment: This worked for me, where Visual Editor was adding extra backslashes trying to display the backslash in \n

Answer (score 4):

Need to keep

1.`android:maxLines="no of lines"`

2.And use `\n` for getting of the next Lines

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was to add the following line to the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    ...
    >
```

And \n shows up as a new line in the visual editor. Hope it helps!

Comment: I am not sure if it's related to the question :)

Comment: I had the same problem that instead of a new line the string "\n" just showed up itself. When i added the line above this wans't the case anymore and the new line showed up

Comment: Maybe it's because you were using `tools:text` and not `android:text` like the OP, but anyways sorry for disturbing :)

Comment: I think i should have clarified it better, thanks to your comment i now did :)  I use `android:text` I think it's just a bug of the visual editor, like the acceptet answer suggests but it is more comfortable to be able to see it :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand now, you are right it is more comfortable :) thanks

Comment: This should be the chosen answer, as it provides practical help instead of just reassurance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `\n` in the file `string.xml`

```
<string name="strtextparkcar">press Park my Car to store location \n</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 android:text="Previous Line &#10; Next Line"
```

This will work.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: <TextView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Prev Line  &#10; New LIne"   />
You need to run in emulator to see it work. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
android:text="Lorem Ipsum \nDolor Ait Amet \nLorem Ipsum"
```

Comment: OP tried almost exactly this but had a leading "-" in his example. If the space in your suggestion makes a difference I would elaborate on that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine. Check it for your app.

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Text 1\nText 2\nText 3"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try:

```
Textview_name.settext("something \n  new line "):
```

In Java file.

Comment: Please provide a proper answer to question, otherwise use comment

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `your_package.R`
and not `android.R`

Answer (score 1):

RuDrA05's answer is good, When I edit the XML on eclipse it does not work, but when I edit the XML with notepad++ it DOES work.

The same thing is happening if I read a txt file saved with eclipse or notepad++

Maybe is related to the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Side note: Capitalising text using

`android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

or similar seems to stop the `\n` from working.

Answer (score 0):

for the new line in TextView just add **\n** in middle of your text
it works..

Comment: but answer relates to the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android) Not "YOUR" question...

Comment: omg..sorry confused by me.please edit your answer..I change my vote positive.

Comment: hey first edit your answer. else I can`t change my vote.

Answer (score 0):

If the TextView is in any Layout (LinearLayout for example), try to change the orientation attribute to vertical as
`android:orientation="vertical"` for the layout or change the `TextView` attribute `android:singleLine="true"` to create a new line after it.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically: myTV.setText("My Text"  +  "\n" + myString);

Answer (score 0):

Create a string in your stings.xml

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="new_line">\u000A</string>
</resources>
```

Then in you code reference the string

```
val linkString = "This is in the first line.${getString(R.string.new_line)}This is on the second line."
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to values> strings inside add string

CHOOSE YOUR CATEGORY"\n"TO WATCH

use "\n" to add new line

then add the string name inside the text view

android:text="@string/category"

Answer (score 0):

You can get text in next line by simply adding  `android:orientation="vertical"` in linear layout in activity.main.xml