# How can I add a line break to a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a newline to a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android)

I would like to manually add a line break to my TextView. Now sure how I can do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `\n`

Comment: It needs to be concatenate as a char and not as string ('\n')