# LIne Break in TextView

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a newline to a TextView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android)

I want to put line break in TextView in Android.
I have used \n but it is not working.