# New line (\n) not Supporting in android?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-edittext, android-view

I am trying to split the single string in to two lines using \n in android but it shows as it is with \n too. I am expecting below,

```
String new = "Hi, How are you";
```

In EditText box I need,

```
Hi,

How are you
```

I know its simple question but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: please don't be harsh on poor guy, looks like he's new to programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are new into android development like me. It's really easy to do...

You just have to do this:

```
editText.setText("Hi,\nHow are you?");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... Actually \n is not working if i pass string to edtitext, but it works inside edittext.settext(); thaks

Comment: I think this is a great question.  I embedded '\n' in a String (Java SE) and was confused as to why EditText did not place a new line.  It only happens in setText.  Hmmm been programming for 18 years and "people do like this" if it saves them time --- quirky behavior that waste my time - like this - I likeeeee.

Answer (score 9):

It's "\n" - a backslash, not a forward slash.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android) for more information about how to make a multiline text view look right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the thing is if i insert a \n in this sting String new = "Hi,\n How are you"; it should come in new line is it.. or i am trying in wrong syntax

Answer (score 4):

In your case, replace `"/n"` and with `"\n"` and also if you need more then one `EditText`, then you must edit properties of `EditText` as below:

```
android:singleLine="false" 
android:MaxLines = "5"
```

if you know the exact number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

yes `"\n"` is supported in android, unfortunately `"/n"` is not supported yet ;)