# show textview in next line

Tags: java, android

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

for(int i=1;i<6;i++)

{

 textView.setText(i);

 textView.setText("\n");

}
```

This is not printing

1

2

3

4

5

Please help me how to print the above output

Comment: What is the result that you expect?

Comment: I want to print 1 2 3 4 5 in separate line

Comment: Try this....textView.setText(i +"\n");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android look here

Comment: You want the `TextView#append()` method, not `TextView#setText()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whenever you call `setText` on a `TextView` you change the entire text.
you should create your `String` first and then set that as your `TextView`'s text.

```
String text = "";
for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
  text += i+"\n";
}
textView.setText(text)'
```

another solution is using `append` instead of `setText`

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
  textView.append(i+"\n");
}
```

Comment: your welcome. you can accept my answer so if everyone faced similar problem, they'll be able to find correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I want from you in one comment to please show what it is printing right now ? and what you want to print ?
if you have 6 textviews then just do this

```
tv1.setText(""+i+"");
tv1.setText(""+i+"");
tv1.setText(""+i+"");
tv1.setText(""+i+"");
tv1.setText(""+i+"");
```

Comment: I had only one textview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String value="";
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
{
    value = value + i + "\n";
}
textView.setText(value);
```