# How to break line(XML code) in android studio?

Tags: java, android

How to show the text in emulator as we need it using text view?
I am writing a code inside android:text element in textview.I want that the code must be shown exactly like how i want it to be means i want to break line when i need so how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840608/how-do-i-add-a-newline-to-a-textview-in-android

Answer (score 2):

I think CDATA xml might be the thing you are looking for. Something like

```
<string name="the_text">
        <![CDATA[
           ... some text <br/>
           ... some text <br/>
        ]]>
</string>
```

You can also achieve the same without CDATA but with "\n"

```
<string name="the_text">"...some text \n ...some text \n"</string>
```

mind the double quotes, without which the line breaks wont happen.